# Lubuntu Package Only Halfway install

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, xubuntu, lubuntu, desktop-environments

How can I repair the download from the terminal?  It was installing Lubuntu 14.04 when the terminal was closed.  After that the Desktop only has a logout option and if I try to do any keyboard shortcuts it will crash.  Luckily I also had Xubuntu on the same Hard Drive.  I would just like to use Lubuntu because I heard of how lightweight it is compared to Xubuntu.

SPECS:

-2 GB RAM

-15 MB Write Speed (Hard Drive is a MicroSD)

-quad core ARM Processor each at 1 GHz

Now you can see why... 
Anyway, any help with this would be much appreciated. :)  I really want to use Lubuntu to get good speed so that I can use it on 1080p.  Thanks. :D

Comment: What desktop only has the logout option? XFCE or LXDE?

Comment: LDXE has the login core and also is the Desktop with only the logout option.  I have Kubuntu, Lubuntu and Xubuntu installed and Lubuntu by far is the fastest.

Comment: All of the other desktops have power off options, then?

Comment: have you tried `sudo apt-get install -f && sudo apt-get install --reinstall lubuntu-desktop`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found out what's wrong.  It's part of the image I downloaded specifically for this product.  Until they patch it there's nothing I can do.  I took another Hard Drive and put their Lubuntu image on there and it still did the same thing.